# Powershell ConvertFrom-Json

Tags: json, powershell

i want to query the Neo4j Database with this Script.
https://github.com/teal-technology-consulting/Invoke-Neo4jQuery/blob/master/Invoke-Neo4jQuery.ps1

But always if i execute this i get this Error:

ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot convert 'System.Byte[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'InputObject'.
Specified method is not supported.

The Problem part is this:

```
$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri2 -Method POST -Body $Query2 -credential $neo4jCreds2 -ContentType "application/json"
if ($Result) {
    if (Test-Path -Path $FilePath -PathType Leaf) { Remove-Item -Path $FilePath }
    $PsResult = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $Result.Content
```

How can i solve this Problem?

Comment: Try using `Invoke-RestMethod` instead; there's a good chance you won't even need to involve conversion.

Comment: If i use Invoke.RestMethode i get ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.

Comment: Of course -- because then `$Result` *is* the result and has no `.Content` property. Check what's in `$Result` afterwards.

Comment: If i do a Write-Host $Result i get some Results for example {"header":{"fields":["KerberoastableUsers"]}}
{"data":["USER111@DOMAIN.LOCAL"]}
{"summary":{}}
{"info":{}}

Comment: but i cant convert this then i get ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: "data":["USER111@DOMAIN.LOCAL"]}

Comment: @xen__ Which version of PowerShell are you using? `$PSVersionTable['PSVersion'].ToString()`

Comment: On this Server its 5.1.17763.1490

Comment: Is this one result, or a bunch of different examples? ```{"header":{"fields":["KerberoastableUsers"]}} {"data":["USER111@DOMAIN.LOCAL"]} {"summary":{}} {"info":{}} ```. Because it’s not valid json if it’s one example - it’s more like json-lines...